# Как сделать блок динамическим

Tags: css

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 40em;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    top: -12em;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 20px;
}

#passwordInput {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: .1em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: -19em;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.38em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
}
```

чтобы если Вводить в `#passwordInput` при необходимости блок расширялся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input',function(){
  this.size = this.value.length||1;
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.fake-input,
input{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
  line-height:1;
  padding:5px 10px;
  min-width:200px;
  margin:0 0 10px;
  max-width:100%;
}
.fake-input{
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>`contenteditable` блок</div>
<div class="fake-input" contenteditable></div>
<div>Стандартный `input`</div>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Через псевдокласс :focus, реагируем на фокус ввода, и просто расширяем на всю ширину блок.

```css
.content {
    text-align: left;
    width: 20em;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    top: -12em;
    background-color: silver;
    padding: 10px;
}

#passwordInput {
    margin-top: .1em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: -19em;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.38em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
    width: 30%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#passwordInput:focus {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <input id="passwordInput" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="input text" 
  onfocus="this.placeholder=''" 
  onblur="this.placeholder='input text'">
</div>
```